# getTelephone problem when empty

Tags: magento-1.7

I am new to php/magento to for warn you. I am making a script to grab some quick info. I am using magento 1.7.0.2. This script works fine until the telephone number is empty and then it stops. It is in a php file. see anything?

```
    <?php


require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$sz=$collection->getSize();
echo "$sz total customers</br>";
$count=0;
echo '<table cellpadding="5"> ';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>&nbsp;</td><td>ID </td><td>Qty </td><td>Name </td><td> Email</td> <td> Phone</td>';
echo '</tr>';
foreach ($collection as $user){
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToSelect('increment_id')
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$user->getId());
    if($orders->getSize() >= 5){
        $u=Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($user->getId());
        $tmpID=$u->getId();
        $name=$u->getName();
        $email=$u->getEmail();
        $phone='NA';
        //$pri;
        $ordercount=$orders->getSize();
        try{
            $phone=$u->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
        }
       catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->errorMessage();
            $phone='NA';
        }

        $count++;
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td> $count </td>";
        echo "<td> $tmpID </td>";
        echo "<td> $ordercount </td>";
        echo "<td> $name </td>";
        echo "<td> $email </td>";
        echo "<td> $phone </td>";
        echo '</tr>';
        //echo "$count-ID: $tmpID  Number Of Orders: $ordercount $name $email $phone </br>";

    }
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case the customer does not have a primary billing address this line with give a fatal error: `$phone=$u->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();`.
So it does not matter if you put it inside a `try-catch` because fatal errors cannot be caught.
So what you need to do is to check if the `getPrimaryBillingAddress` actually exists.
Instead of

```
    try{
        $phone=$u->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->errorMessage();
        $phone='NA';
    }
```

Use

```
if ($u->getPrimaryBillingAddress()) {
    $phone=$u->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
}
else {
    $phone = 'N/A';
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I understand a bit better. I am used to .Net and Java programming. Shouldn't a fatal error like this write to a log file or something? I didn't see any listings.

Comment: @lespaul36. There should be an entry in the php log file. You would see the error on the screen if you had 'display_errors' and error reporting set to 'on'. [See this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 0):

A better way to accomplish this would be to get the info from the order info since the customer info may not be up-to date.

```
foreach ($collection as $user){
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToSelect('increment_id')
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$user->getId());

    if($orders->getSize() >= 5){

        $tmpID=$user->getId();
        $name=$user->getName();
        $email=$user->getEmail();
        $phone='NA';

        $ordercount=$orders->getSize();
        if($user->getDefaultBilling()){
           $phone = $user->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
        }
        ...
```

Comment: Good idea, I have a lot to learn still.